# OpenFlow 1.5.1 Flow table maximum size

Tags: sdn, openflow, pox

I was asked about the maximum number of flow rules an OpenFlow switch can have, so I read the OpenFlow 1.5.1 specification but still couldn't find the answer.

Thank you.

Comment: Search in the switch specs, not Openflow specs.

Answer (score 1):

As said by [@SotirisTsartsaris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1903600/sotiristsartsaris), the number, size and characteristics of the flow tables are only dependent on the switch, not defined by the specification.